# How can I add an explanation of the questions when someone successfully answers my quiz?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a quiz that displays random questions and adds a Short Explanation when someone successfully answers the question.

so if the user plays my quiz, the questions that appear will be random so that the user doesn't easily shoot the answer.

I also want to add a Short Explanation about the correct answer even if the user answered the question wrong

Here's my Code:

```js
// creating an array and passing the number, questions, options, and answers
let questions = [
    {
        numb: 1,
        question: "What does HTML stand for?",
        answer: "Hyper Text Markup Language",
        options: [
            "Hyper Text Preprocessor",
            "Hyper Text Markup Language",
            "Hyper Text Multiple Language",
            "Hyper Tool Multi Language"
        ]
    },
    {
        numb: 2,
        question: "What does CSS stand for?",
        answer: "Cascading Style Sheet",
        options: [
            "Common Style Sheet",
            "Colorful Style Sheet",
            "Computer Style Sheet",
            "Cascading Style Sheet"
        ]
    },
    {
        numb: 3,
        question: "What does PHP stand for?",
        answer: "Hypertext Preprocessor",
        options: [
            "Hypertext Preprocessor",
            "Hypertext Programming",
            "Hypertext Preprogramming",
            "Hometext Preprocessor"
        ]
    },
    {
        numb: 4,
        question: "What does SQL stand for?",
        answer: "Structured Query Language",
        options: [
            "Stylish Question Language",
            "Stylesheet Query Language",
            "Statement Question Language",
            "Structured Query Language"
        ]
    },
    {
        numb: 5,
        question: "What does XML stand for?",
        answer: "eXtensible Markup Language",
        options: [
            "eXtensible Markup Language",
            "eXecutable Multiple Language",
            "eXTra Multi-Program Language",
            "eXamine Multiple Language"
        ]
    },
    // you can uncomment the below codes and make duplicate as more as you want to add question
    // but remember you need to give the numb value serialize like 1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9.....

    //   {
    //   numb: 6,
    //   question: "Your Question is Here",
    //   answer: "Correct answer of the question is here",
    //   options: [
    //     "Option 1",
    //     "option 2",
    //     "option 3",
    //     "option 4"
    //   ]
    // },
];

//selecting all required elements
const start_btn = document.querySelector(".start_btn button");
const info_box = document.querySelector(".info_box");
const exit_btn = info_box.querySelector(".buttons .quit");
const continue_btn = info_box.querySelector(".buttons .restart");
const quiz_box = document.querySelector(".quiz_box");
const result_box = document.querySelector(".result_box");
const option_list = document.querySelector(".option_list");
const time_line = document.querySelector("header .time_line");
const timeText = document.querySelector(".timer .time_left_txt");
const timeCount = document.querySelector(".timer .timer_sec");

// if startQuiz button clicked
start_btn.onclick = () => {
    info_box.classList.add("activeInfo"); //show info box
}

// if exitQuiz button clicked
exit_btn.onclick = () => {
    info_box.classList.remove("activeInfo"); //hide info box
}

// if continueQuiz button clicked
continue_btn.onclick = () => {
    info_box.classList.remove("activeInfo"); //hide info box
    quiz_box.classList.add("activeQuiz"); //show quiz box
    showQuetions(0); //calling showQestions function
    queCounter(1); //passing 1 parameter to queCounter
    startTimer(15); //calling startTimer function
    startTimerLine(0); //calling startTimerLine function
}

let timeValue = 15;
let que_count = 0;
let que_numb = 1;
let userScore = 0;
let counter;
let counterLine;
let widthValue = 0;

const restart_quiz = result_box.querySelector(".buttons .restart");
const quit_quiz = result_box.querySelector(".buttons .quit");

// if restartQuiz button clicked
restart_quiz.onclick = () => {
    quiz_box.classList.add("activeQuiz"); //show quiz box
    result_box.classList.remove("activeResult"); //hide result box
    timeValue = 15;
    que_count = 0;
    que_numb = 1;
    userScore = 0;
    widthValue = 0;
    showQuetions(que_count); //calling showQestions function
    queCounter(que_numb); //passing que_numb value to queCounter
    clearInterval(counter); //clear counter
    clearInterval(counterLine); //clear counterLine
    startTimer(timeValue); //calling startTimer function
    startTimerLine(widthValue); //calling startTimerLine function
    timeText.textContent = "Time Left"; //change the text of timeText to Time Left
    next_btn.classList.remove("show"); //hide the next button
}

// if quitQuiz button clicked
quit_quiz.onclick = () => {
    window.location.reload(); //reload the current window
}

const next_btn = document.querySelector("footer .next_btn");
const bottom_ques_counter = document.querySelector("footer .total_que");

// if Next Que button clicked
next_btn.onclick = () => {
    if (que_count < questions.length - 1) { //if question count is less than total question length
        que_count++; //increment the que_count value
        que_numb++; //increment the que_numb value
        showQuetions(que_count); //calling showQestions function
        queCounter(que_numb); //passing que_numb value to queCounter
        clearInterval(counter); //clear counter
        clearInterval(counterLine); //clear counterLine
        startTimer(timeValue); //calling startTimer function
        startTimerLine(widthValue); //calling startTimerLine function
        timeText.textContent = "Time Left"; //change the timeText to Time Left
        next_btn.classList.remove("show"); //hide the next button
    } else {
        clearInterval(counter); //clear counter
        clearInterval(counterLine); //clear counterLine
        showResult(); //calling showResult function
    }
}

// getting questions and options from array
function showQuetions(index) {
    const que_text = document.querySelector(".que_text");

    //creating a new span and div tag for question and option and passing the value using array index
    let que_tag = '<span>' + questions[index].numb + ". " + questions[index].question + '</span>';
    let option_tag = '<div class="option"><span>' + questions[index].options[0] + '</span></div>'
        + '<div class="option"><span>' + questions[index].options[1] + '</span></div>'
        + '<div class="option"><span>' + questions[index].options[2] + '</span></div>'
        + '<div class="option"><span>' + questions[index].options[3] + '</span></div>';
    que_text.innerHTML = que_tag; //adding new span tag inside que_tag
    option_list.innerHTML = option_tag; //adding new div tag inside option_tag

    const option = option_list.querySelectorAll(".option");

    // set onclick attribute to all available options
    for (i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
        option[i].setAttribute("onclick", "optionSelected(this)");
    }
}
// creating the new div tags which for icons
let tickIconTag = '<div class="icon tick"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></div>';
let crossIconTag = '<div class="icon cross"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>';

//if user clicked on option
function optionSelected(answer) {
    clearInterval(counter); //clear counter
    clearInterval(counterLine); //clear counterLine
    let userAns = answer.textContent; //getting user selected option
    let correcAns = questions[que_count].answer; //getting correct answer from array
    const allOptions = option_list.children.length; //getting all option items

    if (userAns == correcAns) { //if user selected option is equal to array's correct answer
        userScore += 1; //upgrading score value with 1
        answer.classList.add("correct"); //adding green color to correct selected option
        answer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", tickIconTag); //adding tick icon to correct selected option
        console.log("Correct Answer");
        console.log("Your correct answers = " + userScore);
    } else {
        answer.classList.add("incorrect"); //adding red color to correct selected option
        answer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", crossIconTag); //adding cross icon to correct selected option
        console.log("Wrong Answer");

        for (i = 0; i < allOptions; i++) {
            if (option_list.children[i].textContent == correcAns) { //if there is an option which is matched to an array answer 
                option_list.children[i].setAttribute("class", "option correct"); //adding green color to matched option
                option_list.children[i].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", tickIconTag); //adding tick icon to matched option
                console.log("Auto selected correct answer.");
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < allOptions; i++) {
        option_list.children[i].classList.add("disabled"); //once user select an option then disabled all options
    }
    next_btn.classList.add("show"); //show the next button if user selected any option
}

function showResult() {
    info_box.classList.remove("activeInfo"); //hide info box
    quiz_box.classList.remove("activeQuiz"); //hide quiz box
    result_box.classList.add("activeResult"); //show result box
    const scoreText = result_box.querySelector(".score_text");
    if (userScore > 3) { // if user scored more than 3
        //creating a new span tag and passing the user score number and total question number
        let scoreTag = '<span>and congrats! , You got <p>' + userScore + '</p> out of <p>' + questions.length + '</p></span>';
        scoreText.innerHTML = scoreTag;  //adding new span tag inside score_Text
    }
    else if (userScore > 1) { // if user scored more than 1
        let scoreTag = '<span>and nice , You got <p>' + userScore + '</p> out of <p>' + questions.length + '</p></span>';
        scoreText.innerHTML = scoreTag;
    }
    else { // if user scored less than 1
        let scoreTag = '<span>and sorry , You got only <p>' + userScore + '</p> out of <p>' + questions.length + '</p></span>';
        scoreText.innerHTML = scoreTag;
    }
}

function startTimer(time) {
    counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    function timer() {
        timeCount.textContent = time; //changing the value of timeCount with time value
        time--; //decrement the time value
        if (time < 9) { //if timer is less than 9
            let addZero = timeCount.textContent;
            timeCount.textContent = "0" + addZero; //add a 0 before time value
        }
        if (time < 0) { //if timer is less than 0
            clearInterval(counter); //clear counter
            timeText.textContent = "Time Off"; //change the time text to time off
            const allOptions = option_list.children.length; //getting all option items
            let correcAns = questions[que_count].answer; //getting correct answer from array
            for (i = 0; i < allOptions; i++) {
                if (option_list.children[i].textContent == correcAns) { //if there is an option which is matched to an array answer
                    option_list.children[i].setAttribute("class", "option correct"); //adding green color to matched option
                    option_list.children[i].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", tickIconTag); //adding tick icon to matched option
                    console.log("Time Off: Auto selected correct answer.");
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < allOptions; i++) {
                option_list.children[i].classList.add("disabled"); //once user select an option then disabled all options
            }
            next_btn.classList.add("show"); //show the next button if user selected any option
        }
    }
}

function startTimerLine(time) {
    counterLine = setInterval(timer, 29);
    function timer() {
        time += 1; //upgrading time value with 1
        time_line.style.width = time + "px"; //increasing width of time_line with px by time value
        if (time > 549) { //if time value is greater than 549
            clearInterval(counterLine); //clear counterLine
        }
    }
}

function queCounter(index) {
    //creating a new span tag and passing the question number and total question
    let totalQueCounTag = '<span><p>' + index + '</p> of <p>' + questions.length + '</p> Questions</span>';
    bottom_ques_counter.innerHTML = totalQueCounTag;  //adding new span tag inside bottom_ques_counter
}
```

```css
/* importing google fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background: #007bff;
}

::selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: #007bff;
}

.start_btn,
.info_box,
.quiz_box,
.result_box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
        0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.info_box.activeInfo,
.quiz_box.activeQuiz,
.result_box.activeResult {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.start_btn button {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #007bff;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.info_box {
    width: 540px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.info_box .info-title {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 30px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.info_box .info-list {
    padding: 15px 30px;
}

.info_box .info-list .info {
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.info_box .info-list .info span {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #007bff;
}

.info_box .buttons {
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 0 30px;
    border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.info_box .buttons button {
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #007bff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.quiz_box {
    width: 550px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.quiz_box header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.quiz_box header .title {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.quiz_box header .timer {
    color: #004085;
    background: #cce5ff;
    border: 1px solid #b8daff;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 145px;
}

.quiz_box header .timer .time_left_txt {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 17px;
    user-select: none;
}

.quiz_box header .timer .timer_sec {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 30px;
    width: 45px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #343a40;
    border: 1px solid #343a40;
    user-select: none;
}

.quiz_box header .time_line {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #007bff;
}

section {
    padding: 25px 30px 20px 30px;
    background: #fff;
}

section .que_text {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

section .option_list {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    display: block;
}

section .option_list .option {
    background: aliceblue;
    border: 1px solid #84c5fe;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

section .option_list .option:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

section .option_list .option:hover {
    color: #004085;
    background: #cce5ff;
    border: 1px solid #b8daff;
}

section .option_list .option.correct {
    color: #155724;
    background: #d4edda;
    border: 1px solid #c3e6cb;
}

section .option_list .option.incorrect {
    color: #721c24;
    background: #f8d7da;
    border: 1px solid #f5c6cb;
}

section .option_list .option.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}

section .option_list .option .icon {
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    line-height: 24px;
}

.option_list .option .icon.tick {
    color: #23903c;
    border-color: #23903c;
    background: #d4edda;
}

.option_list .option .icon.cross {
    color: #a42834;
    background: #f8d7da;
    border-color: #a42834;
}

footer {
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

footer .total_que span {
    display: flex;
    user-select: none;
}

footer .total_que span p {
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

footer .total_que span p:first-child {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

footer button {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 13px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #007bff;
    border: 1px solid #007bff;
    line-height: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: scale(0.95);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

footer button:hover {
    background: #0263ca;
}

footer button.show {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.result_box {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 25px 30px;
    width: 450px;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.result_box .icon {
    font-size: 100px;
    color: #007bff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.result_box .complete_text {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.result_box .score_text span {
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.result_box .score_text span p {
    padding: 0 4px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.result_box .buttons {
    display: flex;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.result_box .buttons button {
    margin: 0 10px;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #007bff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.buttons button.restart {
    color: #fff;
    background: #007bff;
}

.buttons button.restart:hover {
    background: #0263ca;
}

.buttons button.quit {
    color: #007bff;
    background: #fff;
}

.buttons button.quit:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #007bff;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <!-- start Quiz button -->
    <div class="start_btn"><button>Start Quiz</button></div>

    <!-- Info Box -->
    <div class="info_box">
        <div class="info-title"><span>Some Rules of this Quiz</span></div>
        <div class="info-list">
            <div class="info">1. You will have only <span>15 seconds</span> per each question.</div>
            <div class="info">2. Once you select your answer, it can't be undone.</div>
            <div class="info">3. You can't select any option once time goes off.</div>
            <div class="info">4. You can't exit from the Quiz while you're playing.</div>
            <div class="info">5. You'll get points on the basis of your correct answers.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="quit">Exit Quiz</button>
            <button class="restart">Continue</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Quiz Box -->
    <div class="quiz_box">
        <header>
            <div class="title">Awesome Quiz Application</div>
            <div class="timer">
                <div class="time_left_txt">Time Left</div>
                <div class="timer_sec">15</div>
            </div>
            <div class="time_line"></div>
        </header>
        <section>
            <div class="que_text">
                <!-- Here I've inserted question from JavaScript -->
            </div>
            <div class="option_list">
                <!-- Here I've inserted options from JavaScript -->
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- footer of Quiz Box -->
        <footer>
            <div class="total_que">
                <!-- Here I've inserted Question Count Number from JavaScript -->
            </div>
            <button class="next_btn">Next Que</button>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <!-- Result Box -->
    <div class="result_box">
        <div class="icon">
            <i class="fas fa-crown"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="complete_text">You've completed the Quiz!</div>
        <div class="score_text">
            <!-- Here I've inserted Score Result from JavaScript -->
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="restart">Replay Quiz</button>
            <button class="quit">Quit Quiz</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Inside this JavaScript file I've inserted Questions and Options only -->
    <script src="./questions.js"></script>

    <!-- Inside this JavaScript file I've coded all Quiz Codes -->
    <script src="./quiz.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Since, the _explanation_ is related to a question the explanation data can be within the `questions` data itself for each question. I guess you can have a property called `explanation` . (I haven't gone thru your code or logic. When the answer button is clicked along with the result that the question is answered correct or not, you can also display the explanation text related to that question).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, it almost sounds like form validation feedback in a way.

You can add another blank `div` and give it an id of `additionalInfo` like so.

```
<!-- footer of Quiz Box -->
        <footer>
            <div class="total_que">
                <!-- Here I've inserted Question Count Number from JavaScript -->
            </div>
            <button class="next_btn">Next Que</button>
        </footer>
        <div id="additionalInfo">
            /* Additional Information will fill this part via JavaScript */
        </div>
    </div>
```

In your js at this part. You can specify an adjustment to the innerHTML of that new `div` like this.

```
function optionSelected(answer) {
...
document.getElementById('additionalInfo').innerHTML = "Additional Info Here";
console.log()
...

}else {

}
```

And you can repeat the same behavior in the else statement when the answer is incorrect with adjusted text.

Here's what it looks like. (Ugly but the behavior works for this example).

[image: Quiz with Edits]

The only issue with this is you'll also need to clear the innerHTML and/or hide the div each time the user moves to the next question.

And, you'll want to use a switch statement or other conditional structure to change the output based on the question.

Hope that helps.

Edit:

As prasad_ suggested you could also add the explanation to each object and reference it like `questions[que_count].explanation` and negate the need for a switch or if statements.

If you want differing explanation depending on if they got it right or wrong you would add two properties instead.